# Smooth Animation for Bootstrap 4 collapse

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, css-transitions

I got what I'm looking for but the animation effect isn't smooth as it should. I understand that the animation would be better if I don't have `padding` but I need padding to get the design. How do I solve this problem?

[**JSFiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/2ymxg0p6/)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="block">
            <label class="checkbox"> This is my checkbox
              <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample">
            </label>
            <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="option one">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="option two">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="option three">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.block {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.collapse {
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 30px 15px;
}
```

This is base on Bootstrap 4, the latest version.

Comment: Hope this help. please replace `.collapse` to `#collapseExample`

Comment: Thank You. Tried but while collapsing, there's a certain "drag". Have a look: https://jsfiddle.net/2ymxg0p6/4/

Comment: collapse actually changes into collapsing, before its being set back to collapse, thus the style will be applied after it changes. use another class / id reference there to apply style too.

Answer (score 1):

When you set `.collapse` it first apply the bootstrap style of `.collapse`  and after yours because that there is delay...

Use the id `#collapseExample` to style:

```css
.block {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
#collapseExample{
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 30px 15px;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="block">
            <label class="checkbox"> This is my checkbox
              <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample">
            </label>
            <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="option one">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="option two">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="option three">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT to your comment!**

> There's a "drag" when it closes.

Use jquery `onclick` the `checkbox` and apply `padding` as below:
[fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/2ymxg0p6/36/)

```js
$('.checkbox').on('click', function(){
if($('.collapse.show').length>0)
    $('.collapse').css('padding','0');
else
    $('.collapse').css('padding','30px 15px');
    
});
```

```css
.block {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
#collapseExample{
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="block">
            <label class="checkbox"> This is my checkbox
              <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample">
            </label>
            <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="option one">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="option two">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="option three">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you but this doesn't help. There's a "drag" when it closes.

Comment: This new edit doesn't work either in Chrome (not sure about other browsers). Thanks though. I have resolved it. It's because I added the padding in parent div. I've added my own answer. Thank You so much.

Comment: It works for me in chrome maybe you have to set `!important` however I am happy you solve it

Answer (score 1):

I got it resolved. It's because I added the `padding` in parent div.

```css
.block {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.block__collapse {
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 30px 15px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="block">
            <label class="checkbox"> This is my checkbox
              <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample">
            </label>
            <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
            <div class="block__collapse">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="option one">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="option two">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="option three">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```